# jQuery replace with regex not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to exclude all characters which are not a digit or minus.

What strikes me is that I cannot start with a minus or enter it anywhere. Only after digits and using the keyboard arrow button is entering a minus possible.

What I would like is being able to just enter -60 or something the like.
What should I change?

```js
$('.minus').keyup(function() {
  var txt = $(this).val();
  var nwtxt = txt.replace(/[^\d-]/ig, "");
  $(this).val(nwtxt);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" maxlength="9" class="tekstvakjes minus">
```

Comment: By *exclude*, you mean *remove* right?

Comment: So you want to allow negative numbers only?

Comment: No, I want to include both negative and positive numbers

Comment: All other characters must be removed

Comment: Make input type as text instead number

Comment: @vijaymishra You should change it to an answer. As it fixed the problem.

Comment: Alright, I am writing it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using input type *number* use *text*

Comment: what i was about to say (it is because the number type adds a validation before the `keyup` event fires, and removes the value if not conform, before if even fires the event)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's some kind of browser defence meganism that whenever you insert something that is not a number inside a number input field and you request the value from it, it will simply be null/undefined. On type="text" it looks like this is fine.

Also note your cursor is always put at the end of the text, because you replace the text always. So you can't insert a - (dash) before a number with only keyboard interaction. and a dash anywhere but in front of a number is invalid!

You can try to type in `-60` in the number field as well but you first need to insert. 60 and then the minus character.

also its better to use `$('.minus').input(` instead of keyUp, since you can use the mouse to insert values as well (and the scroll wheel).

```js
$('.minus').keyup(function() {
  var txt = $(this).val();
  console.log("value i got:",txt); //i added this logging to see that you didn't get anything on number.
  var nwtxt = txt.replace(/[^\d-]/ig, "");
  if(nwtext !==txt) //add this if statement so your cursor does not constantly jump to the end!
    $(this).val(nwtxt);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" maxlength="9" class="tekstvakjes  minus" placeholder="number">
<input type="text" maxlength="9" class="tekstvakjes  minus" placeholder="text">
```